# How to run Jetty with JRebel in Eclipse?

Tags: maven, jetty, embedded-jetty, maven-jetty-plugin, jrebel

I am using the jetty maven plugin in Eclipse to deploy my application. This is a part of pom.xml:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.5.v20141112</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                    <version>5.0.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asm-commons</artifactId>
                    <version>5.0.2</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>2</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <stopKey>stop</stopKey>
                <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I have also installed JRebel plugin in Eclipse. So how can i start my jetty server with JRebel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have luckily found the answer in the Maven configuration page (where i call jetty:run) and it works. For those who will also need this and use the JRebel Eclipse plugin, here is the answer:

(I would still be appreciated if someone knows a better way. Maybe in pom.xml, in the configuration of jetty.maven.plugin?)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify JRebel as a JVM argument. As Jetty is started in the same JVM process as Maven, once Maven figures out you have a Jetty configured there, it is already too late.

You have two options in this kind of situation

1. Pass the argument to Maven and as Jetty is started in the same process, it will have JRebel agent hooked. You can use `MAVEN_OPTS` environment variable for this.
2. Use `jetty:run-forked`. It creates a separate JVM process for Jetty and allows to specify arguments through `<jvmArgs/>` configuration option.

Answer (score 0):

Install [JRebel for eclipse](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jrebel-eclipse) using the eclipse Marketplace(Help > Eclipse Marketplace) and restart your eclipse.

Once you created a maven project and configured jetty-server, right click the project and now you should see JRebel option in the context menu. Click `JRebel > Add Jrebel Nature`

[image: Jrebel Eclipse plugin]

Once you do this your project will generate a `rebel.xml` file automatically and should be configured to run with the changes you make in your project without restarting the server. Apart from this I didn't make any specific changes to the project. But JRebel is working fine.

You can also add the JRebel nature to a project by doing this,

```
Help > JRebel Configuration > Projects Tab > Other Projects > Demo_Project
```

Hope this helps.